# Python -the integral from function multiplication

Tags: python, scipy, integral

In python, I have two functions `f1(x)` and `f2(x)` returning a number. I would like to calculate a definite integral after their multiplication, i.e., something like:

```py
scipy.integrate.quad(f1*f2, 0, 1)
```

What is the best way to do it? Is it even possible in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out just a second ago, that I can use lambda :)

```
scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: f1(x)*f2(x), 0, 1)
```

Anyway, I'm leaving it here. Maybe it will help somebody out.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem, I used this (based on the suggestion above)

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad

def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    return x**2

ans, err = quad(lambda x: f1(x)*f2(x), 0, 1)
print("the result is", ans)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.